# Jquery's a FREE grid display

Tags: jquery, grid, flexigrid

I have been using [flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/) for my CMS and I like it except there are some things I think it could do better like get the column headers from the ajax results rather then in the setup of the flexigrid or having the ability to change the buttons on reload things of that nature. I've been considering a mod of the plugin though I'm not sure i really want to do that.

But the question is ... is there something that might be better that I somehow missed when I was looking for grid display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you have a look at [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). I would say it is more powerful than Flexigrid, though it took me a while to get used to the API.